# Extends Spring class from non Spring Class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to write Spring Component Bean and that need to extends from regular class (from abc.jar).

```
@Component
public DefClass extends AbcClass{
..
}
```

This is throwing error AbcClass is a non Spring class, not sure how I can create this as SpringBean. 
I tried to defind in my application-Context.xml

```
<bean id ="abcBean" class ="package.AbcClass" "/>
        <bean id ="defClass"  class ="package.defClass" parent="abcBean"/> 

WEB-INF/classes/applicationCotext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.tivoli.pd.jutil.PDException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not spring project. The class is not available (guess the abc.jar is not added to classpath). Check how you build the application, check the abc.jar exists and included in the classpath.